# How do I change to another view controller in visual studio IOS (clearly explained)

Tags: c#, ios, iphone, xamarin, viewcontroller

This is probably a stupid question, but as I haven't found an answer anywhere else I will ask it here.

My question is: How can I change which view controller is being viewed. In my case I want the user to open the app, and if the user hasn't already filled out the setup form the app will change from the **home page** to the **setup page**.

```
    public override void ViewDidLoad()
    {
        base.ViewDidLoad();
        //Initial setup check
        var window = new UIWindow(UIScreen.MainScreen.Bounds);
        dataBase.SetBool(false, "setUpComplete");



        if (dataBase.BoolForKey("setUpComplete") == false)
        {

        }
        else
        {

        }
    }
```

Thanks to anyone who decides to answer this!

Comment: what is your timerStarted object? is that your logic determining if the form is filled out?

Comment: for that, on app launch, you need to check if a user filled setup form or not, if yes then launch homepage, No load setup page. After form filled then set some value to knowing it is filled.

Comment: actually sorry I copied to wrong piece of code